# Conditional Transpose with join in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I want to create in 1st sheet (Dashboard) an author based automated booklist from my 2nd sheet (StockList) like the link below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16OOzurqBchn5sx5BCUzqVDvU9fA524aK9B5lGezjTUE/edit?usp=sharing

-> If there have multiple books by an author, created one column list with commas (Example: Dashboard!B3).

-> If there have a co-author, the book/books name created also

[image: Dashboard]

[image: StockList]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 {SORT(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(StockList!C2:C, ","))<>"", "♠"&SPLIT(StockList!C2:C, ","), )),"♠"))))),
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(StockList!C2:C, ","))<>"", 
 "♦"&StockList!B2:B&","&"♠"&SPLIT(StockList!C2:C, ","), )), "♦")), "♠")), 
 "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0),, 999^99))), ",$", )}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

### custom Bengali fix:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A!C3:C, ","))<>"", "♦"&A!B3:B&"♠"&SPLIT(A!C3:C, ","), )), "♦")), "♠")), 
 "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)), "select Col1", 0), 
 QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A!C3:C, ","))<>"", "♦"&A!B3:B&"♠"&SPLIT(A!C3:C, ","), )), "♦")), "♠")),
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2", 0), "offset 1", 0),
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A!C3:C, ","))<>"", "♦"&A!B3:B&",♠"&SPLIT(A!C3:C, ","), )), "♦")), "♠")), 
 "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "offset 1", 0)
 ,,999^99))), ",$", )})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, 
This is great, but there is a little bit problem when I copy-paste your code in my original data which is created in my local language (Bengali).
In the #!I11: I22 value is wrong. Accurate value is G12=I22 and I11:I21=G12: G22.

Thanks in advance 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v_RQvFPxLJSN3k6urCcIXt2BsRlbc-sgaiGAP_aH1Y4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v_RQvFPxLJSN3k6urCcIXt2BsRlbc-sgaiGAP_aH1Y4/edit#gid=1827542833

Comment: check the K:L columns in your sheet if its ok or still out of place

Comment: It is as like as before. Accurate value is K11=L22 & K12: K22=L11:L21

thanks a lot